# How to capture only a single click/tap on a MPMoviePlayerController view while controls are hidden?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, uigesturerecognizer

Previously, [I asked about how to capture any touch input on an MPMoviePlayerController's view when the MPMovieControlStyle is set to MPMovieControlStyleNone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384607/how-to-get-touch-click-on-a-mpmovieplayercontroller-view-when-mpmoviecontrolstyle).  It was suggested that I could use a UIGestureRecognizer to do this.

I am able to capture double taps on the screen using a gesture recognizer in this manner, but not single taps.  The code I used for this is as follows:

```
///**********///
singleTapGestureRecognizer =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleClickOnMediaView:)];
singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.moviePlayer.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
[singleTapGestureRecognizer release];
///**********///
```

Why am I unable to capture single taps on an MPMoviePlayerController's view using this code?  Is there something special about how it handles single taps?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384607/how-to-get-touch-click-on-a-mpmovieplayercontroller-view-when-mpmoviecontrolstyle

Comment: @Brad, is this really the same question though? It looks like a follow-up to me.

Comment: @Michael - I believe that this is asking fundamentally the same thing, after reviewing the original question.  It may also be a case described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95833/how-best-to-respond-to-i-want-a-better-answer-duplicates , where the answer given in the first question is unacceptable for what they're trying to do.  I'll see if I can edit it into a distinct question.

Comment: @Michael - OK, I think I've phrased it in a way that makes it clear and separate from the original question.  I was wrong, there is a new issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit old question, but here's a solution, if anyone needs this.
To handle single and double taps on the same view, the single tap recognizer has to wait for the double tap recognizer to fail. Something like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* doubleTapRecon = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap)];
[doubleTapRecon setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[doubleTapRecon setDelegate:self];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecon];

UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTapRecon = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap)];
[singleTapRecon setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[singleTapRecon requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapRecon];
[singleTapRecon setDelegate:self];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTapRecon];
```

Note, that if you are not using ARC, you have to take care of memory managment.

Answer (score 0):

No the above answer will not work to get single tap gesture you have to implement 'UITapGestureRecognizerDelegate' and use the method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Because 'moviePlayer' is also using tap gesture, so to get working our custom single Tap Only above method is required.