# MPMoviePlayerController's view does not recognize touch

Tags: ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, uigesturerecognizer

This is my code:

```
_mediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
_mediaPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
_mediaPlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
[_mediaPlayer.view setFrame: CGRectMake(5, 5, 600,400)];
[playerHolder addSubview: _mediaPlayer.view];
//
[self prepareScreenContentToPlay];
//
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRollTap:)];
singleFingerTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[_mediaPlayer.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
[singleFingerTap release];
```

And action method for gesture recognizer:

```
-(void)handleRollTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender{
    NSLog(@"%@", @"touch");
}
```

MPMoviePlayerController works fine. In addition I want to handle touch on MPMoviePlayerController view but `handleRollTap` never called. Why MPMoviePlayerController's view not works with UITapGestureRecognizer?

---

OK. If `singleFingerTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;` then all works fine as well. But nothing for single tap..

---

Comment: Why are you adding it to the backgroundView instead of the view?

Comment: I tried both cases with `view` and `backgroundView`. backgroundView is latest case, now I change it again to view.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Actually, answer to this is simple:

- set yourself as UIGestureRecognizer delegate
- return YES for delegate methods:

e.g.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture)];
tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

and somewhere else in the code:

```
#pragma mark - gesture delegate
// this allows you to dispatch touches
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
return YES;
}
// this enables you to handle multiple recognizers on single view
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Normaly a gesture recognizer assumes it should do least damage possible. But in rare cases you want to add custom touch recognizers to a view that has his own recognizers, you can set a delegate that can perform resolution when recognizers should work together. Such delegate can decide on every recognizer added to the view. It's a very usefull patern alleviating a lot of pains caused by previous approaches utilising hacking into view internals.

Comment: simply B R I L L I A N T !!!   I don't understand why your answer is was not accepted as so.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. I've added a different solution for people who are still stuck

Comment: Works very well. And my belief is, this has to do with the fact that MPMoviePlayerController most probably adds its own tap recogniser (to show/hide player controls for instance) so this delegate pattern allows both to work simultaneously

Comment: @EgeAkpinar exactly, MPMoviePlayerController and it views use multiple gesture recognisers

Comment: @onmyway133 that's usually the case when your delegate gets deallocated

Answer (score 21):

MPMoviePlayerController has a subview that takes up its entire bounds, and that subview has 3 gesture recognizers on it (in iOS 4.3).

```
mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithURL:movieURL];
mp.frame = aRectangle;

for (UIGestureRecognizer *g in ((UIView *)[mp.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]).gestureRecognizers) {
    NSLog(@"g %@", g);
}
```

will output:

```
g <MPTapGestureRecognizer: 0x6224c30; baseClass = UIGestureRecognizer; state = Possible; cancelsTouchesInView = NO; view = <MPSwipableView 0x6416100>; target= <(action=_tapGestureRecognized:, target=<MPSwipableView 0x6416100>)>>
g <UIPinchGestureRecognizer: 0x6224710; state = Possible; cancelsTouchesInView = NO; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <MPSwipableView 0x6416100>; target= <(action=_pinchGestureRecognized:, target=<MPSwipableView 0x6416100>)>>
g <MPActivityGestureRecognizer: 0x6224640; baseClass = UIGestureRecognizer; state = Possible; cancelsTouchesInView = NO; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <MPSwipableView 0x6416100>; target= <(action=_activityGestureRecognized:, target=<MPSwipableView 0x6416100>)>>
```

So there is already a GestureRecognizer that handles a single tap, but it isn't a UITapGestureRecognizer, but an MPTapGestureRecognizer (a custom recognizer for the movie player).

If you create a generic view and add it to the movie player view hierarchy, you can add touches to it, but it blocks the touches to the movie player (so a single tap won't make the controls disappear).

e.g.

```
UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:mp.view.bounds];
[aView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[mp.view addSubview:aView];
```

This will get your tap, but you break the controls.  There may still be a way to allow it to interact with the other gestures.

Comment: Just realized you're setting your controlStyle to NONE already, so I guess this should work for you!

Answer (score 8):

Just to share my different approach for adding a custom UISwipeGestureRecognizer to the player view without adding a custom view:

```
[[player.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
```

This is to replace the conventional method of calling

```
[player.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
```

as it only works on iPad non-fullscreen mode and on iPhone. When the player goes to fullscreen mode on iPad, the gesture does not work

Comment: [[anyview.subviews objectAtIndex:0] addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture]; Works like a champ... Bro. well done.

Comment: trick is you giving the hint to add a `swipeGesture`! So it preserves the tap geusture to keep it available the Player controls! Bravo! (Y)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIView` `UITouch` event for this.
Take a `UIView` and put `MPMoviePlayerController` inside that:

```
theMovie = [MPMoviePlayerController new];
theMovie.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
[theMovie setContentURL:theURL];
[theMovie setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];
[theMovie setCurrentPlaybackTime:0.2];
[theMovie setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
[self addSubview:theMovie.view];
[viewMovie addSubview:theMovie.view];
```

Use `UIView` touch delegate methods

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan");
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    startPosition = [touch locationInView:self];
    [viewMovie touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"touchesMoved");
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint endPosition = [touch locationInView:self];

    if (startPosition.x < endPosition.x)
    {
        NSLog(@"Left to Right");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Right to Left");
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}
```

Where `startPosition` is a `CGPoint` declared in `.h` file.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is the new gesture recognizer should be added on MPVideoBackgroundView, that is a subview of MPMoviePlayerController view.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest variant of the MPMoviePlayerController the accepted solution still did't work for me.

I also tried 'hacking the UIView stack', and overlaying my own UIView with gesture recognizers. But it all didn't work.

I finally implemented this solution: '[Overriding UIAplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444184/listen-to-all-touch-events-in-an-ios-app)', which seems an over the top way to do it, but in any case it works. Just add some kind of flag or delegate to it when you detect a touch event, and you can then stop the movie.

Answer (score 0):

devdavid has the right idea, but his solution didn't work for me. I guess in newer versions of the player there are other views above the movie player view.

What I did instead was add a `UIView` above the movie player view. This will prevent all gestures from ever getting through to the player, but that was the whole point as I didn't want any controls visible.